# How can I transform one column data to an ordered sequence by groups when using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

how can I handle this problem when using dplyr?

grouped by "id", I want to change the "session" column number which != "NA" to an ordered number 1,2,3,4... 
the data before transforamtion is:

```
    data<-data.frame("id"=c(825010211307012,825010211307012,825010211307012,825010211307012,825010211307012,825010211307021,825010211307021,825010211307021,825010211307021,825010211307021,825010211307021,825010211307021,825010211307021),session=c(1,NA,NA,4,5,1,NA,NA,NA,5,6,NA,8))
      id                  session
825010211307012              1
825010211307012              NA
825010211307012              NA
825010211307012              4
825010211307012              5
825010211307021              1
825010211307021              NA
825010211307021              NA
825010211307021              NA
825010211307021              5
825010211307021              6
825010211307021              NA
825010211307021              8
```

the data after transformation should be:

```
data2<-data.frame("id"=c(825010211307012,825010211307012,825010211307012,825010211307012,825010211307012,825010211307021,825010211307021,825010211307021,825010211307021,825010211307021,825010211307021,825010211307021,825010211307021),session=c(1,NA,NA,2,3,1,NA,NA,NA,2,3,NA,4))
      id                  session
825010211307012              1
825010211307012              NA
825010211307012              NA
825010211307012              2
825010211307012              3
825010211307021              1
825010211307021              NA
825010211307021              NA
825010211307021              NA
825010211307021              2
825010211307021              3
825010211307021              NA
825010211307021              4
```

this is my code:

```
data2 <- data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(session[which(session  != "NA")] = 1:length(which(session != "NA")))
```

but it goes wrong like this:

Error: unexpected '=' in:

"  group_by(id) %>%

mutate(session[which(session  != "

Can anybody tell me how can I achieve this transformation?

I will really appreciate your help!

Comment: Please do not post images. Use `dput` to share data. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

We can `group_by` `id`, create an incremental count on non-NA values in a group and convert `NA` in `session` to `NA` in `temp`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(temp = cumsum(!is.na(session)), 
         temp = replace(temp, is.na(session), NA))


#                id session temp
#1  825010211307012       1    1
#2  825010211307012      NA   NA
#3  825010211307012      NA   NA
#4  825010211307012       4    2
#5  825010211307012       5    3
#6  825010211307021       1    1
#7  825010211307021      NA   NA
#8  825010211307021      NA   NA
#9  825010211307021      NA   NA
#10 825010211307021       5    2
#11 825010211307021       6    3
#12 825010211307021      NA   NA
#13 825010211307021       8    4
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Your Data
data <- 
  data.frame(
    "id" = c(
      825010211307012,
      825010211307012,
      825010211307012,
      825010211307012,
      825010211307012,
      825010211307021,
      825010211307021,
      825010211307021,
      825010211307021,
      825010211307021,
      825010211307021,
      825010211307021,
      825010211307021
    ),
    session = c(1, NA, NA, 4, 5, 1, NA, NA, NA, 5, 6, NA, 8)
  )

# Code
data1 <- data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(id, session) %>%
  mutate(
    session = if_else(!is.na(session), row_number(), NA_integer_)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

# Output
data1
#> # A tibble: 13 x 2
#>         id session
#>      <dbl>   <int>
#>  1 8.25e14       1
#>  2 8.25e14       2
#>  3 8.25e14       3
#>  4 8.25e14      NA
#>  5 8.25e14      NA
#>  6 8.25e14       1
#>  7 8.25e14       2
#>  8 8.25e14       3
#>  9 8.25e14       4
#> 10 8.25e14      NA
#> 11 8.25e14      NA
#> 12 8.25e14      NA
#> 13 8.25e14      NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The important part here is the arrange since NAs are always considered last if you sort your data in a dataframe (so row_number will correctly number the entries in your group). With the if_else statement, we make sure that we only mutate the relevant columns

Regarding your error:
You cant just subset the rows in a mutate() function (with an if_else statement you can mutate on a condition which solves this issue)

Hope that helps

Comment: Now I know why I got a wrong message, thanks for your answer!